# use different java versions for different maven plugins

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have a pom including some plugins. The project's sources are java 17 and as such, the maven build is run with a jdk17+. Now, one of the plugins bound to the `site` lifecycle, let's say plugin `P1`,  is older and it doesn't work with java versions newer than 9 ( because of some deprecated API that is no longer present in the jdk)

My question is: is it possible to somehow configure in the pom that **some plugins** should be run with a different java version?

My intention is to run the plugin as it is, not wanting to re-write it or modify it in any way.
I know about maven `toolchains`, but I don't see how this applies, as that configures the jdk version for all plugins.

Comment: AFAIK Maven runs all of its plugins in the same JVM, so you can't do that. The few cases where you can specify a JVM to run (such as for tests) are when the plugin itself launches a new JVM.

Comment: Which plugin has such issues? Can you name it?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the plugins and the context, you may solve the problem by using separate Maven runs, i.e. run

`mvn clean install`

with JDK17 and then run `mvn some:plugin` with a different JDK.